# Scraping webpage using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrape a webpage using Selenium, I am unable to bypass cloudflare bot check. Previously I used the code below to get the data table from [here](https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/portfolio-investments/fipi-sector-wise). The code below fails due to cloud flare bot check. I am using `undetected_chromedriver` but that also doesn't seems to work.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

dates = pd.bdate_range('2024-02-28', '2024-02-28')

for d in dates:

    try:

        date = d.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
        conv_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%y')
        day = conv_date.strftime("%d").lstrip('0')
        date = '{}/{}/{}'.format(day, conv_date.strftime("%m"), conv_date.strftime("%Y"))

        # url = 'https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/market-information/fipi-lipi/fipi-sector-wise'
        url = 'https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/portfolio-investments/fipi-sector-wise'

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        browser = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        browser.get(url)
        picker = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker')))
        t.sleep(2)
        browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', picker)
        picker.click()
        t.sleep(3)
        browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{date}";', picker)
        # print('clicked the day!')
        t.sleep(5)

        picker = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker1')))
        t.sleep(2)
        browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', picker)
        picker.click()
        t.sleep(4)
        browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{date}";', picker)
        # print('clicked the second day!')
        t.sleep(1)
        search_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="search_btn"]/parent::div')
        t.sleep(2)
        search_button.click()
        # print('clicked search!')
        t.sleep(10)
        dfs = pd.read_html(browser.page_source)
        df_lipi = dfs[0]
        browser.quit()

        todays_date = conv_date

        df_lipi.columns = ['CLIENT_TYPE', 'SEC_CODE', 'SECTOR_NAME', 'MARKET_TYPE',
                           'BUY_VOLUME', 'BUY_VALUE', 'SELL_VOLUME', 'SELL_VALUE',
                           'NET_VOLUME', 'NET_VALUE', 'USD']

        df_lipi.loc[:, 'Date'] = todays_date

        df_lipi = df_lipi[['CLIENT_TYPE', 'Date', 'SEC_CODE', 'SECTOR_NAME', 'MARKET_TYPE',
                           'BUY_VOLUME', 'BUY_VALUE', 'SELL_VOLUME', 'SELL_VALUE',
                           'NET_VOLUME', 'NET_VALUE', 'USD']]

        lipi_columns = ['BUY_VOLUME', 'BUY_VALUE', 'SELL_VOLUME', 'SELL_VALUE',
                        'NET_VOLUME', 'NET_VALUE', 'USD']

        df_lipi.drop(df_lipi[df_lipi.MARKET_TYPE == 'TOTAL'].index, inplace=True)

        df_lipi.iloc[-1:, 0] = 'FIPI_NET'

        df_lipi.iloc[-1:, 2:4] = ['x9999', 'All']

        for string in lipi_columns:
            df_lipi[[string]] = (df_lipi[[string]].replace('[\$,)]', '', regex=True)
                                 .replace('[(]', '-', regex=True).astype(float))


    except:

        print(d)
```

Is there a way to bypass cloudflare? I've added an argument of `headless` but that doesn't seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: What is your detected user-agent string from script ? https://tools.iplocation.net/user-agent

Comment: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Check https://bot.sannysoft.com/ I think you get detected as a bot. And what king of IP do you use? `undetected_chromedriver` is far from 'magic' ;)

Comment: Are you asking public IP? I checked the link you shared. Not sure how to determine if I am getting detected as a bot.

Comment: I mean, is it a proxy, a VPN?, tor, a residential IP, a mobile phone IP?

Comment: It's a residential IP

Comment: Do you have the challenge when using your regular browser?

Comment: yes I have the challenge when using browser.

Comment: So search existing code to bypass Cloudfare and share your search :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257022/discussion-between-lopez-and-gilles-quenot).

Comment: If cloudflare prompts you with a captcha when accessing it as a human, it is hard to imagine you bypassing it with a web scraper without the use of a paid service like 2captcha. Depending on how often you need to scrape it, it could be less than a dollar a month. If that could be a suitable solution, let me know.

Comment: When accessing as a human I have to tick a box. If using selenium there must be a way to tick that box as well.

Comment: Bypassing `Cloudfare` isn't impossible, but if you post a solution here that allows you to bypass it you will find that solution blocked in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Been there. From my experience, bypassing the cloudflare bot protection is impossible without any third party interference.
So, no... there isn't any open source cloudflare by passing techniques. If there is one, then cloudflare already would take measurements to detect those requests as well. The best option would be to use something like BrightData or some other service to by pass it. I think almost all of them have the option to run selenium in their  servers. So it won't be difficult to update your code. And don't worry about captcha and other anti bot protections. Since it will be automatically solved by the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

undetected-chromedriver is help full to bypass but sometimes we are not able to do so

The reason can be that you are not able to mimic human behavior

> Try adding random time delays

**Alternative solutions**

Try rotating your IP Address

use requests-rotating-proxy package

Also, try adding a random header

```
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3" + str(randint(1, 100)))
```